# What is a travel-friendly light alarm or travel-friendly uninterruptable power supply for a light alarm?

Tags: electronic-items, power

I'm looking at moving to a place where electricity may be off at night, and consequently a [Philips HF3250 light alarm](http://amzn.to/2sgzWGN) should still function as a lamp but would forget the time daily.

(Note that I have tried using iPhone apps for this purpose; the light on my phone display hasn't been sufficient for me personally.)

What, if any, uninterruptable power supply options exist that would be small, would have a low power draw, and would give my alarm enough power to not forget the time if electricity is turned off overnight?

Comment: It says it draws 16.5 watts and comes with a transformer to supply 24V.  If that's DC you might be able to take off the transformer and connect it directly to a couple of lead-acid batteries in series, and thus cut out the middleman of the inverter.  Alternatively, perhaps you could look for a lower-power one that's powered via USB?  Then an ordinary USB power bank could serve your purpose - way cheaper than a UPS.

Comment: The HF3250 appears to weigh over 3 pounds and be fairly large - not very convenient to travel with, especially if you need an AC UPS which are typically quite heavy.  Another point in favor of looking for different devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small computer UPS would work, but might be troublesome to transport during travel (due to the sealed lead-acid battery contained within). I've seen them as cheap as [$40 US for a 350VA](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16842102135&cm_re=350VA_UPS-_-42-102-135-_-Product) unit. As a plus you could connect your cellphone, tablet, camera charger etc. and ensure that they were at 100% when you awaken.

You could also consider a similar clock with backup battery built in, but the quality may not be as good as Philips. Some do exist.